# Replace each occurrence of a char with an array element

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file with data :

```
bq --schema
corp:STRING,                                               
region:STRING,                                                                                      
load_date_time:TIMESTAMP)                                      
bq --schema
corp:STRING,                                                                                          
load_date_time:TIMESTAMP)
```

and a String variable as :

```
table1

table2
```

What i want to do is to replace ')' to an array element and the final output should look like :

```
bq --schema
corp:STRING,                                               
region:STRING,                                                                                      
load_date_time:TIMESTAMP table1                                  
bq --schema
corp:STRING,                                                                                          
load_date_time:TIMESTAMP table2
```

The string variable is generated from below file :

```
CREATE TABLE UK_CHAIN_PARM_ADDL_FUNDING(                                      
corp:STRING,                                                            
region:STRING,                                                          
prin:STRING,                                                            
assc:STRING,                                                            
chain:STRING,                                                           
acct_ind:STRING,                                                        
transit_nbr:INTEGER,                                                            
dda_nbr:STRING,                                                        
currency:STRING,                                                        
mask:STRING,                                                            
value_dt:INTEGER                                                              
)                                                                                                   
CREATE TABLE UK_SUPPLEMENTAL_FUNDING(                                      
merchant:STRING,                                                    
acct_ind:STRING,                                                     
transit_nbr:INTEGER,                                                         
dda_nbr:STRING,                                                     
currency:INTEGER,                                                            
mask:STRING,                                                         
value_dt:INTEGER,                                                            
beneficiary:STRING,                                                 
vbc_line_1:STRING                                                  
)                                                

CREATE TABLE UK_REGION_PARM(                                      
corp:STRING,                                                
region:STRING,                                              
end_point:STRING,                                           
currency_code:STRING,                                       
tax_id1:STRING,                                             
tax_id2:STRING,                                             
load_date_time:TIMESTAMP)
```

for extracting just table names i have used below command 
`Tablenames=$(grep -i 'create table' $myfilename | awk -F ' '  'BEGIN{ORS="\n";}{print $3}' | tr "(" "\n")`

So ultimately i want output in format

`bq --schema "schema of the table" -t tablename`

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the answer. So instead of using the array i placed string values inside a file with new line separation.

The code i have written to achieve expected output :

```
while read line1
do
found=$(echo $line1 | grep -c ")")
if [ $found != 0 ];
then
while read line2
      do
           alreadycontainTable=$(grep -c "$line2" NewFileWithTableName.txt)
        if [ $alreadycontainTable == 0 ];
           then
           tableName=$(echo $line2)                       
           echo $line1 | sed -r "s/\)/ -t $tableName/" >> NewFileWithTableName.txt
          break;
        fi
            done < table.txt
else
           echo $line1 >> NewFileWithTableName.txt
fi
done < fileWithBrackets.txt
```